# javascript: call method in an object from string

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to make a controller for my app. I'm not able to do what I want and I don't understand why  :-( I'm not a javascript expert so probably I'm doing something that is not allowed. Error from firebug:

> TypeError: window[("Controller." + where)] is not a function

The error is clear, but why is this happening?

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TB8yr/1/

```
var Controller= function(){
    this.currentpage='home';

}

Controller.prototype.route=function(where){

    window["Controller."+where]();
};

Controller.prototype.goHome=function(){
    alert('route gohome');

}

Controller.prototype.goBack=function(){
    alert('route goback');

}

//////
test=new Controller();
test.route('goHome');
```

Comment: `Controller` is not in `window`. Do `var Controller = window.Controller = ...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `this` instead.

```
this[ where ]();
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMpnF/)

Comment: thank you bro! I did try different combinations but I wasn't clever enough to do it this way! thank you again, it works.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems:

First, jsFiddle runs all of its code inside an IIFE. Declaring a variable in the javascript section will not append it to the window object of the page.

Second, you can't nest properties via dot notation in bracket notation like that. E.g. `['parent']['child']`, not `['parent.child']`.

Lastly, you're trying to call an instance method (goHome) on the constructor function, not an instance. You should be using `this` inside the prototype methods to refer to the instance.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TB8yr/4/

```
var Controller= function(){
    this.currentpage='home';    
}

Controller.prototype.route=function(where){
    this[where]();
};

Controller.prototype.goHome=function(){
    alert('route gohome');    
}

Controller.prototype.goBack=function(){
    alert('route goback');    
}

test = new Controller();
test.route('goHome');
```